# Does a Fixed Effect necessarily mean a Fixed-Slope model in a Mixed Effects Model for Repeated Measures?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear, biostatistics

I'm trying to understand what "fixed effects" means in the following paragraph.

"The SF-36v2 PCS score change from baseline to month 9 was analyzed as prespecified, using a restricted maximum likelihood-based mixed-effect model for repeated measures, including fixed effects for randomization strata, treatment group, categorical time point, and the treatment group × time point interaction, with the baseline value included as a covariate."

Does the Fixed Effect in this case mean they are employing a Fixed Slope model? Would this also mean they are using a Random Intercept + Fixed Slope model (although it isn't explicitly stated)

In general, whenever something is considered as a fixed-effect would it be analyzed with a fixed-slope model (in linear models)? Is fixed-effect and fixed-slope basically the same thing? Thank you

Comment: Could you please edit the question to say what you understand a "fixed slope" model to be? For example, if there's a binary categorical predictor, do you take its associated coefficient to be a "slope" even though it makes an all-or-none contribution to the linear predictor? If there's a reference to the "fixed slope" terminology, please provide that. The "fixed effect" terminology seems to be more frequent, as it can encompass both slopes in the usual sense (e.g., slopes over time) and the associations of categorical predictors with outcome.